# Get value from xml data using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am sending an ajax request to server and server gives data in xml format.

I am getting value from server and store it in a variable.

```
<pre>var strXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Events>
     <EventItem><Country>Hong Kong</Country></EventItem>
     <EventItem><Country>India</Country></EventItem>
   </Events>';
</pre>
```

How do I get no of all the information of EventItem using javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code and format your code properly. *edit:* After your edit, your example doesn't contain XML anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first to parse your string, turning into a real xml structure:

```
toXML = function(text){
    if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        var doc=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.async='false';
        doc.loadXML(text);
    }
    else
    {
        var parser=new DOMParser();
        var doc=parser.parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
    }
    return doc;
}

[...]

var myXML = toXML(strXML);
```

Then you navigate through it. You'll find plenty of ways to do that there : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_examples.asp

Comment: I upvoted, however i suggest turning the if/else the other way around and check for window.DOMParser i.e. if (window.DOMParser){/*code*/}else{/*the ms stuff*/}

Comment: Thanks. While I searched over xpath things last time, I was a bit surprised how poor support is provided to xml stuff : whether we talk about xml AJAX handling (pb in IE), xml parsing, and even xpath selection, it looks like a lot of workarounds, and browser specific code is still to write each time... OK json is great, but xml is still around for a while, isn't it ?